# Cannot connect Pentaho to SQL server that is encrypted

Tags: sql-server, pentaho, pentaho-data-integration

I am using community version 9.4 to migrate sql data to mongodb. While making connection I am getting following error. Ports are opened. SQL browser service is running also.

[image]

And on sql end we get this error in logs.

**Encryption is required to connect to this server but the client library does not support encryption; the connection has been closed. Please upgrade your client library.**

We have checked pentaho running fine on local sql express edition. Need help is there any settings in pentaho for encryption?

Comment: Sounds like the target server has SQL Server Configuration Manager > SQL Server Network Configuration > Protocols (for your Instance name) > Properties > Flags > Force Encryption activated. When this is turned on it means all clients must connect with TLS connection encryption, so you'll need to use a driver in Pentaho that supports connection encryption. For example, JDBC Driver 10.2 for SQL Server (and later) use connection encryption by default.

Comment: I am using latest drivers. I just check your suggestion it is connected successfully when I turn off the encryption.

Comment: jtds-1.3.1 
mssql-jdbc-12.2.0.jre8
mssql-jdbc-12.2.0.jre11

Comment: Already using these but it gives error to include jtds-1.3.1 this jar file. It is using this driver regardless if I include 12.2 or not. I checked to include just this jtds file it is not showing any error and not complaining to use mssql one.

Comment: Driver class 'net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver' could not be found, make sure the 'MS SQL Server' driver (jar file) is installed.
net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver


org.pentaho.di.core.exception.KettleDatabaseException: 
Error occurred while trying to connect to the database

Driver class 'net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver' could not be found, make sure the 'MS SQL Server' driver (jar file) is installed.
net.sourceforge.jtds.jdbc.Driver

Comment: @AlwaysLearning did you get the point?